# What headwear could a triton wear?

Tags: clothing, merfolk

The tritons are a species of aquatic animal with a rather unique appearance. Their head is human-like, apart from the following:

- They have equine ears, that are positioned at around eyebrow level
- They have gills, which are covered by an operculum and are situated across the temple to the angle of the mandible
- They have a wide mouth with carnivore-like teeth
- They have a mane of leaves instead of hair
- They have upwards-facing lobster legs and chelae coming out of the calvaria

Based on this information, what headwear could a Triton wear?

Comment: Why would the need helmets? Projectiles in water aren't effective and most sea fauna can bite through plastic and sheets of metal...unless you make the helmet incredibly thick, like a way too thick.

Comment: Also punches and slashes in water aren't that hurtful to need protection, and if someone is strong enough to hurt you with a punch underwater, it probably makes no difference that you wear a helmet or not.

Comment: Counter argument: while it’s true that helmets have little use against things that can bite through shells and bones. You also have to take into account that helmets can prevent bleeding, which in the water could attract many predators.

Comment: @Rad140 harpoon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Leaves.**

[image: napoleon and gold garland]

https://www.napoleon.org/en/history-of-the-two-empires/paintings/napoleon-and-crown/

Your tritons have leaves for hair.  They would augment these with better, nicer, leaves.  Or possibly artificial leaves.

Answer (score 0):

uh.... maybe seashell conch/cone?

also some of them have some spike to it that can help against bite or contact, maybe put some anemone to it too if you want to add extra protection.

this two example are made of metal so dont take it too literally, but there exist conch as big or wide enough to fit a head (cant upload the image, so i just put the link)

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Helmet_in_the_Shape_of_a_Sea_Conch_MET_DT305562.jpg

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Nagasone_Tojiro_Mitsumasa_Helmet_in_the_form_of_a_Sea_Conch_Shell_1618.jpg

and here some example image that show a conch big enough to fit a person head that i can find.
[image]

from:https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/conch-shell-large.html

oh yeah also clam (dont take that to literal, although real clam that big is easier to find) you can also use smaller one and link it to become maile coif or scale coif (can be applied to small conch or cone too as [willk show in this question using cowrie shell](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/212645/are-seashell-tops-viable-clothing-for-mermaids)).

[image]

otherwise coconut shell or fiber is one of the option, some of them likely drop and drift on the ocean for easy picking or if your triton can move near shallow water the shore likely have some of it.

[image]

from:http://schoolofindustrialdesign.com/viapalermo1/portfolio/raw-helmet/

helmet made of coconut fibre preferable as padding

[image]

from:https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/E_Oc1938-1001-66

also pufferfish to add that extra poison as an addition to the helmet outerlayer.

[image]